# MSB3026 - Could not copy dll to destination, file locked by SonarQube analysis task

Tags: c#, azure-devops, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm facing the bellow issue, I've some files get locked from time to time, and it blocks my Azure Devops CI pipeline.

It seems to be caused by a SonarQube analysis that works in parallel with MSBuild.

> MSB3026 - Could not copy ...dll to ...

I've even tried to pass the following arguments to the MSBuild task (see the below screenshot):

```
/m /nr:false
```

[image]

Based on the following Microsoft Documentation:

[MSBuild Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[File or folder in use errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thus, when disabling the SonarQube analysis task, the file won't be block and the problem is resolved? Have you tried this to make sure it's locked by SonarQube?

Comment: Yes, I've deactivated the SonarQube analysis task and the warning MSB3026 was gone, another fact is that I had always had the same DLL get locked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had a work around fixing the:

> MSB3026 - Could not copy ... because it is being used by another
> process.

MSBuild uses nodes to do parallels projects builds, these nodes remain alive for 15 minutes in order to avoid the high cost of the instantiation of the node.

So that if it happens to build again soon, these nodes can be “reused” and save the process setup cost.
But we can disable that behavior by turning off nodeReuse command-line option:

[image]

According to the Microsoft documentation, in addition to this, we need to deactivate the parallel build in order to avoid this issue.

/m:1

[image]

[MSBuild Command-Line Reference - Visual Studio 2015 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[Troubleshoot pipeline runs - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops)

The downside of this solution is the double build time.

There is a bug in the azure DevOps, when checking the below check box and passing the argument /m:1 will result in duplicated parameters /m and /m:1, so we need to pass the /m:1 /nr:false argument and uncheck the checkbox.

[image: Parallel build checkbox and msbuild arguments]

Comment: Hi @Mselmi, thanks for sharing. You could [mark your answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that people with the same questions can benefit.